# Filters for imagick using exec()

Tags: php, filter, exec, imagick

I have been working on converting PDFs to JPGs, for this I have installed imagick and GhostScript. I have been using exec() in my php code to make the conversion. Now my problem is that if the source of the input pdf is a conversion from doc->pdf, then the image quality is grainy when zoomed. On the other hand I need to keep the image size below 500kb, so I cannot use

- density more than 200.

Is there a way to add any sort of filter before saving the images, so that the jpg quality is improved.

Here is my sample code:

```
    $inputFileName = 'test.pdf';
    $outputFileName  = 'converted.jpg';
    $sourceFile = escapeshellarg( $inputFileName );
    $outputFile = escapeshellarg( $outputFileName );

    $exe = "convert -density 200 -colorspace RGB {$sourceFile } {$outputFile }";           

    $null = "0";

    echo exec( $exe, $null, $result );
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not increasing the density and decreasing the quality? For example:

```
$exe = "convert -density 600 -quality 70 -colorspace RGB {$sourceFile } {$outputFile }";
```